# Creating Stripe Customer - cannot resolve symbol apiKey

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stripe-payments

In Android Studio, even though I'm copying and pasting the code directly from the stripe docs, I'm getting the "cannot resolve symbol apiKey" error from this line:

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_notmyrealapikey";
```

I've already added the stripe line to my gradle:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

I'm successfully exchanging the card information for a token, but now I'm trying to use that token to create a customer. When I remove the Stripe.apiKey line, stripe's error message tells me to add it.

I thought maybe I didn't reference the stripe library correctly but it seems that the only thing I'm supposed to do is add that line to my app's grade file and I did!

I haven't found anyone else online having this problem so I'd be really happy to hear any ideas!

EDIT:

Here is the error I get from stripe without the apikey:

```
com.stripe.exception.AuthenticationException: No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using 'Stripe.apiKey = <API-KEY>'.
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the SDK would just allow you to get an authorization token, that you'd pass to your server to process the actual payment, and create the customer.

Comment: I use my publishable key to get the token, but to create the customer, I need to include my secret key, and for some reason it's not allowing me to include it the way that the docs suggest.

Comment: You should not ever distribute your secret key in your app, the secret key should only be used on your server. You use your publishable key in the app to create the token. Anything that uses that token (like creating a customer), happens server side.

Comment: @MatthewArkin I'm not disagreeing with you, but I'm confused, because the stripe docs shows it like this: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer

Comment: Ahh... I suppose can pass the token to the server and do it all there, but I was just confused by the stripe docs showing the 'Stripe.apiKey = ' part in java.

Comment: yeah, the api docs are server-side api docs not client side. When the API docs show Java they mean server-side java

Comment: That makes way more sense! Thanks!

Comment: @Jack1204 Even i'm facing the same problem..were you able to resolve it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Stripe API library. Most IDEs should automatically tell you to add it but in case it does not add this line to the top

```
import com.stripe.Stripe;
```